# setting height to listview not working (listview inside scrollview)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a layout with `ListView` inside `Scrollview`. I have used the below code to set ListView height,

//Utils.java

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items. 
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        } 

        // Get total height of all item dividers. 
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height. 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true; 

    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

And my Fragment is,

```
public class SliderHome extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_more, container, false);
        comment = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        comment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events. 
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events. 
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break; 
            } 

            // Handle ListView touch events. 
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true; 
        }
    });

    new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json = null;
        String PROFILE_URL = "http://www.example.com/show_comments.php?id="+id;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("All Comments: ", json.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);

        try{
        JSONObject event_comments = new JSONObject(json);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONArray user = event_comments.getJSONArray("comments");

        for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = user.getJSONObject(i);
            //String comment_id = object.getString("id");

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", object.getString("id"));
            map.put("user_id", object.getString("user_id"));
            arraylist.add(map);    
        }

        ListAdapter adapters = new CommentAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
        comment.setAdapter(adapters);
        Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(comment);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

the above code throws some error and the height of listview is not setting.

```
09-10 14:23:49.592: W/System.err(4922): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 14:23:49.592: W/System.err(4922):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:548)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at com.example.Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(Utils.java:21)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at com.example.SliderHome$LoadComments.onPostExecute(SliderHome.java:763)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at com.example.SliderHome$LoadComments.onPostExecute(SliderHome.java:1)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-10 14:23:49.596: W/System.err(4922):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
```

The above error pointing to line number 21 in utils.java, ie, `item.measure(0, 0);`

How to solve this issue.

And my layout is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/slider"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="170dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
          android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        .............

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#0B1F20" >
        </ListView>
     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Is tehre any way to solve this.

Comment: You are doing 2 things wrong here. `ListView` should never have height of `wrap_content` and it shouldn't be used inside of a `ScrollView`

Comment: What would you like to achieve here? ListView should never be inside a ScrollView. In fact no scrollable container should be inside of another scrollable container for the same scrolling direction.

Comment: Like the previous comments suggest it's a really bad idea to have a listview inside a scrollview . Looking at your layout you can achieve the same by adding the `ImageView` as a header to the `ListView`.

Comment: @akash93 :- ok, then how can i set height of listview by calculating the height of items in listview.

Comment: You don't need to ... Just replace your scrollview with just the listview and add an imageview as the header